# An error has occurred during report processing : Multiple Values Selection

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssrs-2008

I received an error while running my report - "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)"

Here is my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(I.Id)   AS Count_Id
      , U.FirstName  AS AffectedUser
  FROM IncidentDimvw
       JOIN (s) ...
 WHERE  WIAUF.DeletedDate IS NULL
   AND DSD.LanguageCode = 'ENU'
   AND (I.CreatedDate BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate))
   AND IC.IncidentClassificationValue = (@Classification)
 GROUP BY DSD.DisplayName, U.FirstName
HAVING COUNT(I.Id) = (@CountId)
```

When ever I Select All in the filter it returns the following error. Don`t know what to do further to resolve this error.

```
Incorrect syntax near ','.
 ----------------------------
 Query execution failed for dataset 'AffectedUser'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
 ----------------------------
 An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
```

Kindly give me a better solution for it.

Comment: Below code i used in my dataset.

'SELECT Count(I.Id) AS Count_Id,U.FirstName AS AffectedUser
FROM
IncidentDimvw
Join(s) ...

WHERE
WIAUF.DeletedDate IS NULL
AND DSD.LanguageCode = 'ENU'
AND (I.CreatedDate BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@EndDate))
AND IC.IncidentClassificationValue = (@Classification)
 
GROUP BY DSD.DisplayName,U.FirstName
Having Count(I.Id) = (@CountId)'

Comment: Please can you add **all** of the code for the query for dataset 'AffectedUser' to the query? (You can amend your question by clicking on the `edit` link directly below the tags in your question.) Additionally, can you try running the query for the dataset in SSMS (with appropriate values specified for parameters) and include the rest of the error message in the question?

Comment: Your best option is to run SQL Server Profiler to see *exactly* what code is being run by the report, in terms of the parameters being passed. Once you have this, as per @MarkBannister you can run the code in SSMS which should point you to the specific syntax error.

Comment: I am working on SQL report builder 3.0. I don`t know how to put it all on SSMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved. Actually the problem is in my query.

```
WHERE Fieldname IN (@Parametername)
```

This is the right query to select multiple values.

Comment: Answer doesn't appear to be related to question.

Comment: @Mark May be you are right & I thankfull for your cooperation, but my question is, Multiple Values Selection, an error window pop up that shows "An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)" Incorrect syntax near ','.
I used a WHERE clause for the parameter
The querry is
Where Fieldname = (@Parametername)
but after a long time some one suggest me and also equals(=) sign compare the value and show result if values are same

But in my senerio i select multiple values and it resolved by IN operator because IN operator allows you to specify multiple values in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem now got resolved .
use  WHERE Column_name In(@parameter)
Instead of WHERE Column_name =(@parameter)